# Merge Sort Program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge(int a[],int l,int m,int r)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int n1= m - l + 1;
    int n2= r - m;
    int L[n1],R[n2];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        L[i]=a[l+i];
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        R[j]=a[m + 1+ j];
    i=0;j=0;k=l;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2)
    {
        if(L[i]<R[j])
        {
            a[k]=L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            a[k]=R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<n1)
    {
        a[k]=L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<n2)
    {
        a[k]=R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    if(l<r)
    {
        int m = l+(r-1)/2;
        mergeSort(a,l,m);
        mergeSort(a,m+1,r);
        merge(a,l,m,r);
    }   
}

void printArray(int a[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d   ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int a[]= {
                12,76,34,45,63,98
             };
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    printf("The element entered in array   ");
    printArray(a,n);
    mergeSort(a,0,n-1);
    printf("The element after sorting    ");
    printArray(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a merge sort program. Why it's giving runtime error if anyone can explain? There is no error in this program

I have tried this 10 times. And unable to find the solution.

Comment: "Why it's giving **runtime error** if anyone can explain? There is **no error** in this program" - you contradict yourself! So what is it error or no error? Then see [ask], we are no debugging service. Use a debugger to track down the specific poisiton you get the error. Watch the variables and try for yourself first.

Comment: @Olaf - Agree with the contradict-part. But it is perfectly ok to ask "why isn't this code working" questions. It just requires that the question includes the complete code base for reproducing the error. This question did so it is an ok question for SO.

Comment: @4386427: They are not ok. Please follow the links and see the CV page! It is very clear: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem** or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers**. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: @Olaf From the close reason: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`. This tells me that such questions are OK. However, for this specific question, it can be argued that the "problem statement" isn't real clear.

Comment: @4386427 Rule changes shall be discussed on meta, not comments to a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `mergesort(a, 3, 5)` the following happens:

```
int m = l+(r-1)/2;  // 3 + (5-1)/2 -> 3 + 4/2 -> 3 + 2 -> 5
mergeSort(a,l,m);   // So this will call: mergesort(a, 3, 5) again
```

In other words: An endless loop.

Maybe you want this instead:

```
int m = (l+(r-1))/2;

        ^       ^
         notice
```

> So how did I find the bug?

Very easy - just use some printf-debug.

First I added a print in the start of `mergesort` - like:

```
void mergeSort(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    printf("mergesort %d %d\n", l, r);  // Debug print
    if(l<r)
    {
        int m = (l+(r-1))/2;
        mergeSort(a,l,m);
        mergeSort(a,m+1,r);
        merge(a,l,m,r);
    }   
}
```

and got the output:

```
mergesort 3 5
mergesort 3 5
mergesort 3 5
...
...
```

which told me that there was an endless loop for input values 3 and 5.

Then I added a print of `m`

```
void mergeSort(int a[],int l,int r)
{
  printf("mergesort %d %d\n", l, r);
    if(l<r)
    {
        int m = (l+(r-1))/2;
        printf("m %d\n", m);
        mergeSort(a,l,m);
        mergeSort(a,m+1,r);
        merge(a,l,m,r);
    }   
}
```

and got the output:

```
mergesort 3 5
m 5
mergesort 3 5
m 5
mergesort 3 5
m 5
```

so obviously `m` was calculated wrongly.

Looking close at

```
int m = l+(r-1)/2;
```

is was clear that the addition should be **before** the division. A set of `(....)` was missing.

Hope you can use this debug example for your own debug.

Comment: @ShiveshChandra - glad to help :-) Please pay attention to the debug technic - maybe that can help you going forward. :-)